# How to know which app is opened?

Tags: java, android

I want to know when any app is opened. Clearly to say, i am making service that blocks some apps ( according to user ) and i want to check app is this similar to any app in the blocklist and abort that app process. And does it need root access ?

Comment: @user370305 the link you give is about to know which apps is running, i want to know when any app is launching and interrupt it , just make to continue or close it

Answer (score 0):

You are able to know which apps are currently opened

```
ActivityManager manager = 
    (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Now from the **`processes`** find your app and write the logic as per your requirement.

Comment: then there is no event or something to know when any app begin launching ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> runtasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (int i = 0; i < runtasks.size(); i++) {
Log.d("Running task", "Running task: " + runtasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString() + "\t\t ID: " + runtasks.get(i).id);
}
```

Comment: it is also about running tasks, i want to make service as guide, when any app begin launching it 1st go to guide and asks "may i launch ? "

Comment: Is same thing possible in IOS?