# Which advantages give to developer ROOT access on android ?

Tags: java, android

I use android platform about 1-2 years, and there are some apps which need to be root access. When i creating android app what give me this ROOT access ? Clearly to say,

`if (haveRootAccess) doSomethingSpecial()`

what can be `doSomethingSpecial()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access `/data/data/` folder of the device which helps to get data of each application installed in device and one can manipulate it.

you can able to run command like `su` `ping` `ftp` etc with command terminal.

Can add additional commandfile `/system/bin` folder.

Comment: i can do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069503/how-to-know-which-app-is-opened with any way using root access or other things ?

Comment: here, I dont think so any requirement of root access.

Comment: ok, then i can interrupt to launching any app before it is launched ?

Comment: google it, 'm confident you dint require root access but to your query no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Root access is required for apps which needs to execute operations on command-line with **Super User** rights. Its just like using Terminal on linux system with command *sudo*.

```
//for example
Process suPro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

For more info, read [this](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.se/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html)